# Configurable, validated configuration file format for python

Tags: parameters, configuration

I'm currently developing a small project which has a lot of input parameters. Currently, I'm using a YAML file to store all configuration parameters. However, it seems to lack some nice features.

Is there a better format which fulfils the following requirements:

- I can add comments explaining the current variable set
- I can add options, where the choose can pick one or multiple items, e.g. with a radar box
- I can have some form of input validation (e.g. no numbers in a string, etc..)
- It looks nice for people just using the package (no raw YAML format, e.g.)

Best

I checked formats like YAML, TOML and nothing seems to support this in a modern way.